# Execute a specific command in a given directory without cd'ing to it?

Tags: linux, bash, cd-command

Is there a way to execute a command in a different directory without having to `cd` to it? I know that I could simply `cd` in and `cd` out, but I'm just interested in the possibilities of forgoing the extra steps :)

Comment: It's rather trivial to make a script that does this: `echo "#!/bin/bash; cd $1; exec $2" > /usr/local/bin/execindirectory; chmod +x /usr/local/bin/execindirectory`.  Might need to put a little more effort if you want it to actually support option "tags" such as `-d` and stuff.

Comment: As user-unknown states in an answer, all the examples you've given here and in comments are better addressed by other solutions, so it's unclear if there is actually a problem that needs solving here. Can you come up with a better example?

Answer (score 102, accepted):

I don't know if this counts, but you can make a subshell:

```
$ (cd /var/log && cp -- *.log ~/Desktop)
```

The directory is only changed for that subshell, so you avoid the work of needing to `cd -` afterwards.

Comment: That's what I usually do.

Comment: Nice, I had forgotten altogether about sub-shells, very handy in this case.

Comment: To avoid potential chaos, sub out the semicolon with two ampersands: `$ (cd /var/log && cp *.log ~/Desktop)`. That way, if the directory doesn't exist, no further commands are executed.

Comment: Note for anyone else as naive as me: the $ at start isn't part of the command, just everything after it.

Comment: TNX, worked on arch/zsh.

Answer (score 31):

Not to undermine the value of answers given by other people, but I believe what you want **is this:**

```
(cd /path/to && ./executable [ARGS])
```

Note the parens to invoke `cd` in a sub-shell.

Comment: I don't think so. As I understand, he wants to end up in the initial directory.

Comment: Oh, I totally forgot to wrap that into sub-shell.  Corrected my answer, thank you.

Answer (score 18):

Some programs have options with which you can tell them to [*chdir(2)*](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/chdir.html) themselves (e.g. GNU *tar*’s `-C`/`--directory`).

Outside of such programs though, something will have to *chdir*. You could write and use some sort of compiled “binary” program instead of having the shell do it, but it probably would not yield much benefit.

In a comment in another answer, you gave an example:

```
execindirectory -d /var/log "cp *.log ~/Desktop"
```

Since the `*.log` pattern is expanded by the shell itself (not *cp*), something will have to *chdir* to the directory before having a shell evaluate your command.

If you are just interesting in avoiding having to “cd back”, then you can use a subshell to isolate the effect of the *cd* from your working shell instance.

```
(cd /path/to/dir && some command)
```

You can package this up in a shell function.
(I dropped the `-d` option from your example usage since there is little point to this command if the directory is actually optional.)

```
runindir() { (cd -- "$1" && shift && eval " $@"); }

runindir /var/log 'cp -- *.log ~/Desktop'  # your example
runindir /var/log cp -- \*.log \~/Desktop  # eval takes multiple args
                                           # which it concatenates
                                           # with spaces prior to
                                           # evaluation
```

```
runindir /var/log cp -- \*.log ~/Desktop   # it is not okay to expand tilde first
                                           # as the expansion would then be
                                           # interpreted as shell code and
                                           # would break if your $HOME contained
                                           # characters special to the shell.
```

Comment: I like this solution, except, personally I'd use pushd/popd

Answer (score 11):

The [`env` program from  GNU `coreutils-8.28` (released 2017-09-01) and newer has `--chdir`](https://github.com/coreutils/coreutils/commit/57dea5ed07471b2192cc5edf08993e663a3f6802):

> env: add --chdir option
>
> This is useful when chaining with other commands that run commands in
> a different context, while avoiding using the shell to cd, and thus
> having to consider shell quoting the chained command.

```
$ env --help | grep chdir
  -C, --chdir=DIR      change working directory to DIR
```

So on a modern system (RHEL 8+, Ubuntu LTS 20.04+) you can just:

```
env --chdir=/tmp pwd
```

This is especially useful if you need to use `sudo` and don't want to mess up quoting the arguments.

```
FILENAME="Some file maybe with spaces.txt"
FILEDIR="/some/directory maybe with spaces"
sudo env --chdir "$FILEDIR" \
  zip "/tmp/$FILENAME.zip" "$FILENAME"
```

Comment: Nice find, though not portable. For example, busybox env doesn't support the chdir option, so it won't work on Alpine linux.

Comment: For machines that don't have GNU `env` (e.g. macOS), a portable one-liner that would act similarly is `sh -c 'cd -- "$1" || exit 1; shift; "$@"' -- DIR CMD [...]` (where `DIR` is the desired working-directory and `CMD [...]` is the command, with any optional arguments)

Answer (score 6):

Here is something that should let you `cd` back where you were (using Bash), since not forgetting to do so seems to be the purpose of the question:

```
# Save where you are and cd to other dir
pushd /path/to/dir/that/needs/to/be/current/dir

run-your-command

# Get back where you were at the beginning.
popd
```

(EDIT: slightly shorter version, thanks to @Random832)

Comment: you could just `pushd other-dir`, rather than `pushd .; cd other-dir`

Comment: @Random832, good point!

Answer (score 4):

Sadly, your example:

```
execindirectory -d /var/log "cp *.log ~/Desktop"
```

doesn't need a change to the dir, because

```
cp /var/log/*.log ~/Desktop
```

would do the same. Can't you get closer to your real problem? Because we might know a better solution for that too.

A complicated way to solve your problem, which is far away from the elegance of Michaels solution, is the usage of find, which has a switch '-execdir' to be performed in the dir, where a file is found. Badly adopted to your example:

```
find /var/log -maxdepth 1 -type f -name "*.log" -execdir echo cp {} ~/Desktop ";"
```

Maybe it is useful for your real problem. -okdir instead of -execdir will ask you to confirm every invocation.

-okdir and -execdir might need gnu-find to be installed, which is typically used on Linux.

Comment: Of course, if there are *a **lot*** of files in `/var/log`, then `cp /var/log/*.log ~/Desktop` might overflow the maximum command line size when `cp *.log ~/Desktop` doesn’t.

Comment: Who has thousands of logfiles in /var/log? Just tested a copy with 13.000 files in a long pathname without problem.

Answer (score 2):

How about `./your/path/command.sh`?

Comment: No, I actually meant something like the following: `execindirectory -d /var/log "cp *.log ~/Desktop"`.

Comment: I'm perfectly aware that this isn't strictly necessary, by the way, I'm just interested in if it can actually be done.

Answer (score 2):

If I have a **bash script** in `/home/user/` and the **bash script** is `myscript` there are a lot of solutions.

`/home/user/myscript`

```
#!/bin/bash
echo "WELCOME BASH"
```

Run `chmod +x /home/user/myscript`

1. create an `alias` and execute by alias name

   - Temporary `alias` — run this in the terminal

     `alias myscript="/home/user/myscript"`
   - Permanent `alias` in `~/.bashrc` (/home/user/.bashrc) — add/edit this to your `.bashrc` file

     `alias myscript="/home/user/myscript"`

   Now run in terminal: `myscript`
2. add the directory path to `$PATH` and execute by name

**Run in terminal:**

3. `/home/user/myscript`
4. `./home/user/myscript`         This works only if your current directory is `/`.
5. <del>`/home/user/./myscript`</del>
6. `. ./home/user/myscript`         This works only if your current directory is `/`.
7. `source ./home/user/myscript`      This works only if your current directory is `/`.
8. <del>`source /home/user/./myscript`</del>
9. `source /home/user/myscript`
10. `bash /home/user/myscript`
11. `bash ./home/user/myscript`      This works only if your current directory is `/`.
12. <del>`bash /home/user/./myscript`</del>

**References** to explain differences among some of the above:

- [What is the difference between executing a Bash script vs sourcing it?](https://superuser.com/questions/176783/what-is-the-difference-between-executing-a-bash-script-vs-sourcing-it)
- [What is the difference between sourcing ('.' or 'source') and executing a file in bash?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/43882/what-is-the-difference-between-sourcing-or-source-and-executing-a-file)
- [Revisiting Bash vs Source difference](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1096236/revisiting-bash-vs-source-difference)
- [Source vs . why different behaviour?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/309768/source-vs-why-different-behaviour)

I run this commands in a terminal on a Debian 10.9 and they work.

GNU bash, Version 5.0.3(1)-release (x86_64-pc-linux-gnu)

Comment: (1) ``script`` is a bad *example* name for a script.  I suggest that you use things like `foo`, `myscript`, or perhaps something derived from your name, or the OP’s.  (2) Your answers are fundamentally the same as [bdictator’s answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/13803/80216), which missed the point of the question; hence, so do yours.  (3) Answer 8 simply ***will not work**.*  Several others depend on an unstated assumption; in other words, they will not work in general.  (4) Answers 5, 9, and 13 are just silly.  … (Cont’d)

Comment: (Cont’d) … (5) If you’re going to post a list of similar answers, you should explain how they differ (because they most certainly are not equivalent). … … … … … … … … … … … … … … … … … Please do not respond in comments; [edit] your answer to make it clearer and more complete.

Comment: The question on the title is | Execute a specific command in a given directory without cd'ing to it?

Comment: The answer differ from bdictator, there is alias, path, source and bash

Comment: @G-Man Says 'Reinstate Monica' I think you can edit the title and the question if i missed the point of the question? my english is not the best.

Comment: I wish Stack Exchange made it easier for users to indicate that English is not their first language.  The question title *is* ambiguous; it becomes somewhat clearer if you read the second sentence of the question body, and then Naftuli Kay’s comment on bdictator’s answer. … … … … … … … … … … … … … … … … … … … … … … Imagine if the `ls` command didn’t take arguments (or you were limited to running it without arguments), so the only way to list the files in `/var/log` would be `cd /var/log && ls`.  The question is “How can I run `ls` ***in*** `/var/log` without needing to `cd` there?”  … (Cont’d)

Comment: (Cont’d) …  Thank you for responding to my comments (and for doing so politely).  You’ve obviously put a lot of work into this, so I have changed my downvote to an upvote. (But, really, injecting `/./` in the middle of a pathname ***is*** silly.)

Answer (score 0):

I'm not expert enough to know how universally it would work, but the `source` command lets you load/execute something in another directory. I use this to activate a virtual environment, e.g. `source ./venv/bin/activate`.

Comment: Thanks for contributing,  but this is largely the same as [bdictator’s answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/13803/80216), but with the added complication of the ``source`` command, which doesn’t help.

Comment: I initially tried exactly that (bdictator's answer), but it didn't work. It did when I included the `source` command, though. Is there a reason why one or the other would work with specific commands?

Comment: Well, the point is that bdictator’s answer is a wrong answer for this question (see Naftuli Kay’s comment), and so is yours.  See my comments on [Blockchain Office’s answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/709871/80216).  So you and bdictator are both answering different questions, and using *their* answer on *your* problem is like comparing oranges and pumpkins.

Comment: OK, I missed the OP's comment on bdictator's answer. My response was to the way the original question was stated (I got here because I had the same question, as I understood it), which as you say turns out to be a different question.

Answer (score 0):

```
(cd dir && cmd)
```

as already provided is the approach you'd want to use when `cmd` is an external command. In many shells, the subshell doesn't involve an extra process, as `cmd` is often executed in the process that was started to run the subshell, so the difference with `cd dir; cmd` is that the fork is done earlier.

In those shells that don't, you can always change it to `(cd dir && exec cmd)` to do the optimisation by yourself.

You can't use that approach though if the command you want to perform in that directory need to make permanent changes to your shell environment (such as setting some variables, change the umask, open some files...).

In:

```
(cd /dir && cmd && result_files=(*.out))
```

The `result_files` array would only be set in that subshell and lost when that subshell terminates.

Using:

```
pushd /dir && {
  cmd && result_files=(*.out)
  ret=$?
  popd
  (exit "$ret")
}
```

(Or solutions using `cd /dir` and `cd -` instead of `pushd`/`popd`), besides being cumbersome are potentially unreliable as the `$OLDPWD` could end up referring to a different directory after `cmd` has returned.

If you do that in an interactive shell and press Ctrl+C while `cmd` is running, your old directory will also not be restored.

The correct way to temporarily change to a different directory is to `open()` `.` on some file descriptor (with `O_PATH` where supported so you don't even need to have read access to the directory), `chdir()` to the new dir and then `fchdir()` to the saved fd. That will bring you back to where you started even if your old current directory was renamed or removed.

However, I don't know of any shell that has an interface to `fchdir()` let alone `open(O_PATH)`. On Linux however you can approximate `fchdir(x)` with `chdir("/dev/fd/x")`, so in the `zsh` shell, and assuming you have read access to the current working directory, you could do something like:

```
{ 
  cd /some/dir && cmd && result=( *.out(N) )
} always {
  cd -P /dev/fd/3
} 3<.
```

The `always`  block is always executed regardless of errors, `break` `return` or `continue` in the *try block*.

You could also set the close-on-exec flag to that file descriptor  so it's no leaked to commands in the *try block* with:

```
zmodload zsh/system

sysopen -u3 -o cloexec . && { 
  cd /some/dir && cmd && result=( *.out(N) )
} always {
  cd -P /dev/fd/3
  exec 3<&-
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a zsh shell alias and function to run a command in a directory, without using a subshell (in case the command has side effects on the shell environment that you'd like to keep):

```
alias direval='noglob _direval'
function _direval() {
  pushd -- $1 && {
    shift && eval " $@" 
  } always {
    popd
  }
}
```

Usage examples:

```
direval my-git-repo/scripts git ls-files
direval /usr/bin ls g*
direval /usr/bin GEXECS=$(echo g*)
```

The `noglob` in the alias means you don't have to worry about escaping glob characters; they will be evaluated later in the directory you chose. Unfortunately I couldn't figure out a way to make `direval /usr/bin GEXECS=g*` work, but using `direval /usr/bin GEXECS=$(echo g*)` is an OK workaround.

Credit for some of the pieces here that came from other answers: thanks Stéphane Chazelas for the `&& { ... } always { popd }` idea, to Bruno for using pushd / popd, and to Chris Johnson for the idea of making a shell function to do this.