# What is the difference between sourcing ('.' or 'source') and executing a file in bash?

Tags: bash, shell

What's the difference between executing a script like this:

`./test.sh`

and executing a script like this:

`. test.sh`?

I tried a simple, two-line script to see if I could find if there was a difference:

```
#!/bin/bash
ls
```

But both `. test.sh` and `./test.sh` returned the same information.

Comment: Apologies if this is a duplicate - upon further investigation, I found some pages with relevant information by searching for 'bash dot' instead of 'bash .'.

Comment: Just as `test.sh` is not the same as `./test.sh` (the first invokes a `PATH` search), so are `. test.sh` and `. ./test.sh` different in the same way (the former invokes a `PATH` search).  Many shells seem to implicitly include `.` at the end of `PATH` when doing a `.` path search, but this behavior is not standard.  Thus, it is more accurate to compare `test.sh` vs `. test.sh` and `./test.sh` vs `. ./test.sh`.

Answer (score 123, accepted):

`./test.sh` runs `test.sh` as a separate program. It may happen to be a bash script, if the file `test.sh` starts with `#!/bin/bash`. But it could be something else altogether.

`. ./test.sh` executes the code of the file `test.sh` inside the running instance of bash. It works as if the content file `test.sh` had been included textually instead of the `. ./test.sh` line. (Almost: there are a few details that differ, such as the value of `$BASH_LINENO`, and the behavior of the `return` builtin.)

`source ./test.sh` is identical to `. ./test.sh` in bash (in other shells, `source` may be slightly different or not exist altogether; `.` for inclusion is in the POSIX standard).

The most commonly visible difference between running a separate script with `./test.sh` and including a script with the `.` builtin is that if the `test.sh` script sets some environment variables, with a separate process, only the environment of the child process is set, whereas with script inclusion, the environment of the sole shell process is set. If you add a line `foo=bar` in `test.sh` and `echo $foo` at the end of the calling script, you'll see the difference:

```
$ cat test.sh
#!/bin/sh
foo=bar
$ ./test.sh
$ echo $foo

$ . ./test.sh
$ echo $foo
bar
```

Comment: Also adding `echo $$` to the script will show the difference quite clear. The `$$` variable holds the PID of the current shell.

Comment: Another usage scenario is using the `. ./test.sh` call from within another shell script to use functions that are described within test.sh. I mean, it is not just variables that you can set, you can also create new functions in this way which are then callable from bash, or some other script. `. /usr/libexec/company/tools; custom_command "variable`"

Answer (score 12):

Running a script the first way runs it as a child process. Sourcing (the second way), on the other hand, runs the script as if you entered all its commands into the current shell - if the script sets a variable, it will remain set, if the script exits, your session will exit. See `help .` for documentation.

Answer (score 4):

Another thing that I note is that if you have an alias like this:

```
# add into .bashrc_aliases
alias ls='ls -lht'
```

With `./test.sh` you'll get a normal `ls` output (and a different PID than current shell):

```
auraham@pandora:~/iso$ ./test.sh 
dsl-4.4.10.iso  test.sh
3136 # PID
```

With `. test.sh` or `. ./test.sh` you'll get a more detailed output (and the same PID than current shell):

```
auraham@pandora:~/iso$ echo $$
2767 # shell PID

auraham@pandora:~/iso$ . test.sh 
total 50M
drwxrwxr-x  2 auraham auraham 4.0K Jul 30 15:41 .
-rwxrwxr-x  1 auraham auraham   32 Jul 30 15:41 test.sh
drwxr-xr-x 50 auraham auraham 4.0K Jul 30 15:30 ..
-rw-rw-r--  1 auraham auraham  50M Jul 28 17:24 dsl-4.4.10.iso
2767 # PID
```

Comment: You can include this in `.bashrc` 

`if [ -f ~/.bash_aliases ]; then
    . ~/.bash_aliases
fi`

Then, put your aliases in `.bash_aliases`.

Comment: Of course, but don't you still have to use the `alias` keyword? (Maybe that's just a mistake in you post -- on line 3?)

Comment: totally correct, my mistake. Thanks @EmanuelBerg

Answer (score 0):

Usually, a `./file` is just a way to point to a file, which in this case, is equivalent to the PWD (present working directory) path followed by the file name used.

```
$ pwd
/home/isaac/me/bin/

$ realpath ./file
/home/isaac/me/bin/file
```

It also happens that a path at the start of a line (first argument or argument 0) signals the shell to try to execute that file. If it is a shell script, most probably, the shell will load it to execute it in a new execution environment. If it is some other form of valid executable, the shell will try to execute it via the kernel `exec` command.

Adding an initial dot to a command line (only works if it is the whole argument zero) will allow a shell script (not an external executable) to be loaded with the same execution environment already present.

```
$ . ./file        # that exact same file as above, now it is sourced
$ source ./file   # an equivalent (but longer) command.
```

Of course, if the directory is not set in the path (not starting dot), some searching will be involved to find the specific file to be sourced.

In bash:

> If filename does not contain a slash, filenames in PATH  are used to find the directory containing filename.

And, if in POSIX mode, the PWD is also used to search for the `filename` given.