# What is the difference between ./script and . ./script?

Tags: linux, scripting, environment-variables, bashrc

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Using ‘.’ to execute files in bash](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/43882/using-to-execute-files-in-bash)

I was trying to figure out how to export my environmental via script instead of changing my .bashrc file.

I found [this old useful post](http://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/linux-newbie-8/how-to-export-environment-variable-from-a-bash-script-344057/) that said:

> Variables can only be exported to subordinate processes, you can't
>   pass them back up to the parent. If you really want your script to
>   affect the parent shell's environment, run the script as
>
> ```
> . ./yourprogram
> ```

I just want to know what the difference is between `. ./script` and `./script`?

When I look at it, they booth mean to me, run the script from the current directory?

Comment: I checked your link and you are right. The answer to the linked question answers my question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`./script` runs a file called 'script' in the location `./` - which translates to 'here' (i.e. the current directory).  That script is executed in a sub-shell, and anything that script does to the environment is lost when the sub-shell ends.

`. ./script` tells the current shell to execute a file called 'script' in the location `./` in the *current* shell without a sub-shell, so anything it changes in the environment remains when the script stops.

`.` is shorthand for the command `source`.  You can lookup source with man (`man source`).

`/home/bob/script` is the same as `./script` if you are in the directory `/home/bob`

`. /home/bob/script` is the same as `. ./script` if you are in the directory `/home/bob`

Answer (score 2):

`./script` means running the file `script` which is in the current directory. Generally shell while running a script first calls `fork()` and `exec()` i.e. the script will run in child process ( i.e sub-shell )

`. ./script` is similar to `source ./script` which means running the script in the current shell without any `fork()`

Answer (score 1):

The first is a shell command `.` followed by a path. The second is just a path.

The shell command `.` "sources" the file that follows into the current shell session. So variables that are set in `./yourprogram` will then be visible in the session or script that executed `. ./yourprogram`.

The second command, on the other hand, just requests that `./yourprogram` be executed. This will only work if `./yourprogram` has the appropriate execute permissions, and is either

1. a binary
2. a script in some language that begins with a "shebang"
   line, for example `#!/bin/sh` or `#!/usr/bin/python`
3. or it's a
   script in the language of the current shell, lacks a shebang line,
   but the current shell defaults to executing script files in a child
   shell in such cases

In none of those events will changes to shell/environment variables performed by `./yourprogram` be visible afterwards in the calling script or session.