# What does dot mean in this command?

Tags: bash, command-line

According to the [Flask official tutorial](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.11/installation/#installation):

> Now, whenever you want to work on a project, you only have to activate
>   the corresponding environment. On OS X and Linux, do the following:
>
> ```
> $ . venv/bin/activate
> ```

This works. However, when I try running `./venv/bin/activate` and `venv/bin/activate`, both gave me `-bash: venv/bin/activate: Permission denied`.

My question is: What does the `.` do?

Comment: ... or [What is the difference between `./script` and `. ./script`?](http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/52385/86440) if you prefer, there's quite a selection already!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The dot is, in this case, synonymous to the shell keyword `source`. What it does is to read the file and execute each line as if typed directly into the command line. Permission wise all you need is read access to the file.

Sourcing a file with shell commands is not the same as invoking a shell script: A shell script needs execute permission (this is why you got Permission denied) and will launch its own (non-interactive) shell.

Comment: can `source` substitute `.` in *all* cases?

Answer (score 1):

The dot mean execute the scirpt in current shell. Normally shell scirpts are executed in subshell, but when you exit the scirpt you loose all the variables, set inside. This way (with dot) is how to keep the variables values, changed directories and so on.

Comment: The magic word I'm missing here is `source`.

Comment: The question is about dot. For source: http://superuser.com/questions/46139/what-does-source-do

Comment: That is exactly the same command.