# shell script unable to set environment variable with the grepped value

Tags: linux, bash, shell

In the shell script, I want to grep a value from the log file and set as the value of one environment. In the log file, there is one line like this:

```
SOME_PATH=/some/specific/path
```

In my shell script, I grep the `SOME_PATH` keyword, and I got the above line and split it with `=`, but I'm now able to set the environment variable:

```
line=`grep "SOME_PATH" /path/to/the/log.log`
path=${line##*=} 
export SOME_PATH="$path"  #I cannot change the environment variable with this line.
```

And if I just have the script like below in my bash file, the environment variable changes if I source the bash file.

```
export SOME_PATH=/some/specific/path
```

Comment: Are you expecting the variable's value to change in the parent shell? if so you will need to *source* the script rather than run it - see [Using '.' to execute files in bash](http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/43882/65304)

Comment: Hi, I used source to run my file, but with grepped value, the env variable won't be set.

Answer (score 2):

In principle your solution should work, but it is not robust. If, for example, you have in the `grep`ed file a comment (or something else) in the matched line, say, like:

```
SOME_PATH=/some/path # this is some path
```

then the comment will also be part of the name that you expand in `path`. To check that inspect what's actually in the path, e.g. by `printf "'%s'\n" "$path"`.

Note that setting an environment variable this way will only affect the shell instance where you set it and any subprocesses, but not the surrounding environment.