# Script called by .bashrc with "exit" prevents log-in

Tags: shell-script, bashrc

I caught myself out; I couldn't log into root after I made a script and called it from `~/.bashrc`.

***~/.bashrc***:

```
#... do stuff then run my script
source ~/myscript.sh
```

**~/myscript.sh**:

```
#!/bin/bash
if [myConditional]; then
  exit
fi
# otherwise do stuff
```

What I had hoped was that when I log in as root, myscript.sh would be run, and if myConditional was true, myscript.sh  would stop running any further commads, but would return to .bashrc and the user would still be logged in as root as usual. But instead, `exit` stopped me from being able to log in at all! It just returned me to a login prompt.

Is there another command I should be using besides `exit`? Obviously I could just extend the `if` statement by having an `else` statement and removing `exit`, but for educational purposes I'd like to know if there is a more appropriate approach. (Also partly because I want to avoid deeply nested `if` statements; it could be quite a large script)

Comment: Your text says "run", but you actually `source` your script - so the shell you are `exit`ing from is the original one

Comment: Or maybe [What is the difference between sourcing ('.' or 'source') and executing a file in bash?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/43882/what-is-the-difference-between-sourcing-or-source-and-executing-a-file-i/43885#43885).

Comment: *Or*, you really mean to `source` - if so, please [edit] to say what your goal is. What's in the "script"?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`source filename.sh` (or `. filename.sh`) runs the contents of `filename.sh` [in the current interpreter](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Bourne-Shell-Builtins) (essentially, as though you copied the contents in at that point). Consequently, `exit` will exit that interpreter.

If you just want to run the script as a separate program, don't use `source`: just `~/myscript.sh` will run it if you make it executable first with `chmod +x ~/myscript.sh`, or you can use `bash ~/myscript.sh` if you prefer. That starts up a new shell to run your script, just like if it were any other program on the system.

On the other hand, if you do really mean to `source` your script (because it's going to set environment variables, say), you can stop running the rest of the file without affecting `.bashrc` and the shell that ran it [using `return`](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#index-return):

> `return` may also be used to terminate execution of a script being executed with the `.` (`source`) builtin, returning either *`n`* or the exit status of the last command executed within the script as the exit status of the script

In that case, your `myscript.sh` file would have:

```
if [[ condition ]]
then
    return 0
fi
```

with the effect you wanted.