# Iterate over multiple files in a folder and assign value

Tags: bash, shell-script

I have a folder named `MyProperties` and it contains multiple `.properties` files like `1.properties`, `2.properties`, `3.properties` and so on. Each file has contains something like:

```
keyname=value
```

What should I write here as the value in the properties file so that it gets assigned or replaced? How do I iterate over these in a bash script and assign the value to the key?

Pseudo code:

```
#!/bin/bash
valuetobepassed="something"
#iterate over each file in the folder and replace/assign value corresponding to keyname
```

Comment: If you want the properties available to the shell, but don't want them on the main level (where they could trash `HOME` or `PATH`), and don't need or want to support the full shell syntax, you could arrange to read them to an associative array...

Answer (score 1):

If you really have multiple files with `varName=value` pairs, then all you need to do is [source](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/43882/22222) it. So, iterate over all `.properties` files and source each of them :

```
for file in /path/to/MyProperties/*.properties; do
    . "$file"
done
```

You now have all your variables defined in your script. To illustrate:

```
$ cat foo.properties 
foo="bar"
$ echo "$foo"  ## no value

$ . ./foo.properties 
$ echo "$foo"
bar
```

This assumes your `.properties` files have *nothing but variable=value pairs*. When sourcing, each line of the file will be executed in the shell running the script doing the sourcing. So, any commands in your `.properties` files will also be executed. And any attacker with access to `MyProperties` can add a malicious command there. So only do this if you can be certain of the files' contents.

Note that it's important that the path given to the `.` builtin contains a `/` character (hence the `./foo.properties` above) as otherwise the file is looked up in the directories of `$PATH` instead of the current directory (in the case of `bash` and when not in POSIX compliance mode, `. file` looks for `file` in the current working directory if it has not been found in `$PATH`).

Answer (score 1):

You can use `sed` to replace values in files:

```
#!/bin/bash

new_value=5
for f_name in MyProperties/*.properties; do
     sed -i "s/^keyname=.*$/keyname=$new_value/" "$f_name"
done
```

Comment: gives error --sed: -e expression #1, char 32: unknown option to `s'