# Can the script detect a difference between "bash somescript" and "bash -c 'source somescript'"?

Tags: bash, shell-script

Looking at the (prior) title, it has great chance to be marked as "duplicate".

I have a script (`test.sh`) that does not take any arguments. I call it in following two ways :

```
bash "test.sh"
# BASH_ARGC=()
# BASH_ARGV=()

bash -c "source test.sh"
# BASH_ARGC=([0]="1" [1]="0")
# BASH_ARGV=([0]="test.sh")
# BASH_EXECUTION_STRING='source test.sh'
```

The only differences I found are those three bash variables. As test.sh does not take any arguments, I presume those differences are irrelevant.

Are there any other differences ?

Put another way, what (in `test.sh`) can work in one calling method, but not in the other ?

***Update 1***

@JdeBP, @Stephen Kitt

Thank you for answering, but my point is not about `detection` of the differences, but about real differences that could affect an average programmer.

$0 being different is rarely "used" by an average programmer.

Comment: See https://superuser.com/questions/176783/what-is-the-difference-between-executing-a-bash-script-vs-sourcing-it

Comment: Sourced files run in the current shell and executed have their own.  Any variables, functions, etc defined in your script will now be defined in your shell if you source it.  Also if your script calls `exit` at all and you source it you will exit from your current shell session.

Comment: @jesse_b but given how the script is invoked in both cases here ...

Comment: It isn't a duplicate.  This could do with a better title, because everyone is going to _wrongly_ leap for the usual duplicate.  The usual duplicate question is asking about a different scenario to this.  Here, there's a child process non-interactive shell _in both cases_.

Comment: The POSIX-conformant form of the question, probably best addressed as a separate Q&A, is of course whether a (conformant) script can detect the difference between `sh somescript` and `sh -c '. somescript'`.

Comment: `"$0"` will likely differ

Comment: @A B, "$0" did differ, but it does not affect the functionality of the script.

Comment: @Andy Dalton, I had a look at your reference, I don't think it applies to this case.
Please answer my questions directly.

Answer (score 1):

```
bash -c "source test.sh"
```

is a somewhat unusual way of running `test.sh`, combining `source` with a separate shell.

This can be detected by looking at `$0`; a typical form would be

```
if [ "${0##*/}" = "test.sh" ]; then
    # being run directly
else
    # being sourced
fi
```

since `$0` won’t reflect the script when `source` is involved.

Apart from argument handling, there shouldn’t be any practical difference from `test.sh`’s perspective between

```
bash test.sh
```

and

```
bash -c "source test.sh"
```

however the latter form will prefer a `test.sh` on the `PATH` to a `test.sh` in the current directory.

See [What is the difference between sourcing ('.' or 'source') and executing a file in bash?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/43882/86440) for details of the differences when sourcing a script in the current shell.

Comment: Try putting a different `test.sh` in a directory on your path.  (-:

Comment: Stephen, both forms just look at current directory to find the script, if I'm not mistaken.

Comment: @Philippe, no, see [the documentation for `.`](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Bourne-Shell-Builtins.html#index-_002e): “If *filename* does not contain a slash, the `PATH` variable is used to find *filename*. When Bash is not in POSIX mode, the current directory is searched if *filename* is not found in `$PATH`.”