# What effect does a dot character . have in a crontab?

Tags: cron

I have picked up a habit of including `.` from some blog post:

```
0 0 * * * . /usr/local/bin/somescript.sh
```

...instead of:

```
0 0 * * * /usr/local/bin/somescript.sh
```

For instance a visual cron schedule expression  editor [cron.guru](https://crontab.guru/#0_8_*_*_Mon_.) considers using the character as an error, but my scripts appear to have ran as specified at least until now.

Comment: Be aware that `crond` runs the command with a fairly arbitrary shell: nominally /bin/sh, which may be a link to another shell (like ksh), and may also be overridden by a SHELL directive in the crontab. Sourcing your command script means its own shebang gets ignored, and the default shell may not like the syntax.

Comment: And, your "`.`" will malfunction if your `source`d file is not a `/bin/sh` compatible script. If it's an ELF binary or an incompatible script, BOOM!

Comment: I've moved the scripts to `/usr/local/bin`, they appear in `$PATH` now. The question had a bad location.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`cron` passes the entire command, including a dot if present, to a shell for execution; so `.` is the corresponding shell command, which “sources” the script in the current shell instead of launching a new process to run it. For an `.sh` file, that would probably be a new shell.

See [What is the difference between sourcing ('.' or 'source') and executing a file in bash?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/43882/86440) for details.

[cron.guru](https://crontab.guru/#0_8_*_*_Mon_.) only validates schedule expressions, *i.e.* the part of the `crontab` entry which defines when it should run; that’s why “0 8 * * Mon .” is marked invalid — that’s not a valid schedule expression.

Comment: @ilkkachu thanks for the edit. I didn’t think it worth distinguishing, since anything that works when sourced involves a shell ;-).

Comment: @StephenKitt, yeah of course :D But the opposite of going from `whatever` to `. whatever` might not work. I wasn't sure if to edit or comment or how to phrase it though...

Comment: @ilkkachu right, converting from one to the other could be useful information to add, especially since the linked Q&A doesn’t address it directly. Even going from `. whatever` to `whatever` might not work since `. /path/to/whatever` only requires `whatever` to be readable, not executable.