# How to start a bash script on Oracle Linux

Tags: linux, oracle

What is the right way to start a bash script on **Oracle Linux**?

on a normal Linux server I use ./script.sh

### But here is what I got when I do the same on Oracle Linux

```
[user@server ~]$ ./script.sh
bash: ./script.sh: Permission denied
```

---

### The permissions are correct

```
[user@server ~]$ ll script.sh
-rwxr-x--x 1 user oraexpl 317 Jul  4 15:42 script.sh
```

---

### It works ok if I omit the "/" character

```
[user@server ~]$ . script.sh
It works
```

---

### It works ok if I execute it with bash

```
[user@server ~]$ bash script.sh
It works
```

---

In my script, I do have the Shebang /bin/bash

**Is this behavior normal?**

Thanks for your feedback

Comment: You write that you execute `./script.sh`, but your shell complains about `./script_shell.sh`. Please clarify if this is a typo, or if `script.sh` internally calls `script_shell.sh`.

Comment: Related: [What is the difference between sourcing and executing a file in bash](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/43882/377345)

Comment: What is the first line in the script? Is it invoking a valid interpreter? And is it possible that the file system is mounted `noexec`?

Comment: I vote for `noexec` :-)

Comment: Bingo, you got it:

/dev/mapper/vg_root-lv_home on /home type ext4 (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime)

Comment: The CIS benchmark calls for `noexec` on removable media (reasonable), on `/dev/shm` (also reasonable), and on `/tmp` (causes lots of problems, with podman, a few flexlm daemons, a few java apps, etc.). Doesn't call for the flag on `/home` so I think you have an over-zealous admin or security group.

Comment: What is the output of `findmnt --target .`? (run in same dir as script)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Following up as an answer so this can be accepted and searched. Mounting `/home` with the `noexec` option will cause this behavior. The mount option is not prescribed by the CIS benchmark so you may have reason to appeal to the system administrator or the security group. If you have `sudo` privileges, try removing `noexec` from the options in `/etc/fstab`. If something like puppet or chef overrides this, you can use

```
sudo mount -o remount,exec /home; ./script.sh
```

as a temporary fix for the problem.

Comment: That would fix the problem, but also allow users to execute their own binary files.
Which my customer don't want. But thanks for your help. now I have the explanation for why I have this behavior.

Comment: @Angel115 Just an FYI. Similar to using `bash ./script` you can use `/lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 ./exe` to run a binary executable that you normally would be able to execute. Mounting the FS `noexec` will slow people done but doesn't eliminate the problem.