# SSH session termination on script error when sourcing multiple sub-scripts

Tags: bash, ssh, scripting, error-handling, r

I'm facing an issue with SSH on a server. Running individual scripts (source s01.sh, etc.) works fine, with errors displayed in the console. However, when using a master script to source these scripts, the SSH connection unexpectedly terminates upon encountering an error. The master script `master.sh` is as follows:

```
#!/bin/bash
set -e

source s01.sh
source s02.sh
Rscript s03.R
source s04.sh
```

I source the master script in interactive SSH session using

```
source master.sh
```

With set -e, I expect the script to stop at errors, but instead, it's causing the entire SSH session to drop. This only happens with the combined script, not with individual sourcing. Why does this occur, and how can I keep the SSH session from closing on script errors?

I am aware this might involve SSH server configurations, but I'm unsure which settings to investigate.

Comment: PLease [edit] your question and explain how you are running the combined script. Is it `ssh server script.sh` or do you first open an interactive session and then `script.sh`? or is it `bash script.sh`? We need the details to be able to reproduce this.

Comment: @terdon Done! Thanks for pointing out.

Comment: Ah, and do you _need_ to source the `master.sh`? Looks like it would be fine to just execute the master, in which case you wouldn't have the problem.

Comment: @terdon Actually I already made `master.sh` executable but forgot about not needing `source` to execute it. Thanks for clarifying this.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The reason this is happening is because you are sourcing the master script. I can reproduce the behavior you describe using these two toy examples:

```
terdon@oregano ~ $ cat ~/scripts/foo.sh
#!/bin/bash
set -e
source /home/terdon/scripts/bar.sh
echo "done!"

terdon@oregano ~ $ cat ~/scripts/bar.sh
#!/bin/bash

echo "start"
false
```

Now, if I open a new terminal and run `. ~/scripts/foo.sh` (note that `source` is a non-portable bash alias to the standard `.` command, so `. foo` is the same as `source foo`), the terminal I opened just exits. And if I try it in an ssh session, the ssh session exits. Why? Because sourcing means executing the commands and applying them to the current session. So since one of the scripts causes an error (the command `false` just exits with `1`), the `set -e` causes the session to exit. It doesn't just kill the script because you have told it to apply the commands to the current shell session by sourcing instead of executing.

However, from your example, it looks like you don't need to source the master script, all you want is to source the other scripts which presumably are setting up the environment needed by your R script. So just execute instead of sourcing and you should be fine:

```
/path/to/master.sh
```

Or, if you haven't made it executable:

```
bash /path/to/master.sh
```

See [this post](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/43882/22222) for more on sourcing vs executing.