# Source vs . why different behaviour?

Tags: bash

I recently learned, that

`. ./.a.a` and `./.a.a` is the same.

However trying `source source .a.a` gives an error. IMO, `.` being Bash alias for `source` shouldn't behave differently, so what am I missing?

Bonus, why is `. .` OK while `source source` is not?

Comment: You could have chosen a clearer name for your example :). In any case, whatever  gave you the idea that `. script` and `./script` are the same thing? [They most certainly are not](http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/43882/22222). Also, `.` is not an alias to `source`. It's the other way around. `.` is the standard and `source` is an alias of `.`.

Comment: After spending some time looking at shell scripts, you get used to the `.` command, but I mean `source` is just such a better command, when you see `source somefile` in a script you immediately know what that statement does, but `. somefile`    not only is not obvious what it does, you can easily miss the `.`  character  altogether

Comment: _Bonus, why is . . OK while source source is not?_ - in how far the error message `bash: .: .: is a directory` on `. .` is ok needs to be explained.

Comment: @terdon - absolutely right. The original example was `. ./.a.a .` to be honest. :-D A quiz of sorts, if you will. :-) Linked question is awesome, many thanks. What gave me that idea: the fact that I had seen no difference in executing files this way and the fact I read somewhere `.` is an alias for `source`. :-)

Answer (score 39, accepted):

You can't just replace `.` with `source` everywhere; if

```
. ./.a.a
```

works, you can replace the first `.` (at least in Bash):

```
source ./.a.a
```

The second `.` represents the current directory, you can't replace that with `source` (especially not `./` with `source` as you've done).

```
source source
```

would be OK if you had a file called `source` in the current directory, containing something meaningful for your current shell. I can't see how `. .` would be OK...

Also, `. ./.a.a` and `./.a.a` aren't the same, the second form runs `.a.a` in a separate shell. See [What is the difference between sourcing ('.' or 'source') and executing a file in bash?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/43882/86440) for details.

Answer (score 13):

`source` is a shell keyword that is supposed to be used like this: `source`*`file`* where *`file`* contains valid shell commands. These shell commands will be executed in the current shell as if typed from the command line. Now, `.`*`file`* does exactly the same.

Beyond that `.` alone means "the current working directory" as in `./xyz` ("`xyz` in this directory") or `a/b/./c/./d` (which is identical to `a/b/c/d`).

Beyond that `.` in a filename has a meaning only by convention as in `.foobar` which indicates a "hidden" file (not really...) or as in `foobar.pdf`, which indicates a file format by the suffix (here `.pdf`).

These different meanings cannot be interchanged.

Comment: `.` is in no way outdated. It, unlike `source` is the portable, [POSIX-defined](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html#dot) way of sourcing a file. The `source` alias is shell-specific and can be either absent (for example in `dash`) or behave differently from the standard `.`.

Comment: Thanks @terdon, [Wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Source_\(command\)) says that the source as a dot (.) is not acceptable in C shell, where the command first appeared.

Comment: @NoamManos perhaps, but the C-shell is not POSIX, so it can (and does) behave very differently.